# Google Spreadsheets tickbox with time-driven reset adds value to additional columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Very green and looking for some help with a potential script for an internal client tracking document. Ideally, when you check the box column D (value = TRUE), column G will increase +1 and column H will decrease -1. I want the checkbox to reset at midnight, but keep the values in G and H.

Can someone help this green gal out?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/187N0kY8wh-7I-SSGTqwjqdFLy6wCB-ujIj301KXtZhE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

**You are basically asking two questions.**

---

You need an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) function that will allow you to increase and decrease the values of the columns G and H respectively, when you check the box in column D:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
 
  if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 4 && e.range.getValue() === true) {  
    const plus_val = as.getRange(row,7).getValue();
    const minus_val = as.getRange(row,8).getValue();
    as.getRange(row,7).setValue(plus_val!=''?plus_val+1:1);
    as.getRange(row,8).setValue(minus_val!=''?minus_val-1:-1);
  }
}
```

---

You then need to set up a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) for function `clearCheckboxes()` to clear (make False) the checkboxes in column D:

```
function clearCheckboxes(){

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
sh.getRange('D2:D'+sh.getLastRow()).clearContent();
}
```

---

### Instructions:

1. Choose the sheet name of your choice; adjust `Sheet1` in both scripts to the name of the sheet you are interested in.
2. Copy & Paste both `onEdit(e)` and `clearCheckboxes()` to an empty script in the script editor, and click save. Whenever you check a checkbox in column D, the desired calculations will be made.
3. Create a time trigger for `clearCheckboxes()`. To do that, you can click on the project's triggers and create a time-driven trigger for this particular function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const sr=2;
  if(sh.getName()=='Your Sheet Name' && e.range.columnStart==4 && e.range.rowStart>sr && e.range.getValue()=="TRUE") {
    e.range.offset(0,3).setValue(e.range.offset(0,3).getValue()+1);
    e.range.offset(0,4).setValue(e.range.offset(0,4).getValue()+1);
  }
}

function toRunAtMidnight() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sr=2;
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Your Sheet Name');
  sh.getRange(sr,4,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,1).setValue("FALSE");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to incorporate and this was perfect. Thanks!